# PHP: From SQL values to html content

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Recently I learned PHP and SQL and I am currently working on a project that aims to exploit both. However, I am not sure about the approach.

GOAL:
I have stored values in SQL in a table of 16 columns and 460 rows. I want to pull the data of 20 rows and return them in html elements in that order. e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHEN main_cat = "Design" ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 20
```

So the first HTML element will display all the values in the first row, the second all the values in the second row, and so forth. Something like this:

```
<div class="tablevalue">
<h3>ROW1_Value1</h3>
<span>ROW1_Value2</span>
<span>ROW1_Value3</span>
<span>ROW1_Value4</span>
<span>etc</span>
</div>

<div class="tablevalue">
<h3>ROW2_Value1</h3>
<span>ROW2_Value2</span>
<span>ROW2_Value3</span>
<span>ROW2_Value4</span>
<span>etc</span>
</div>
etc...
```

How do I pull these and store them with php so I can access them and return them in html using php's echo function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: General best practice for pulling data from MySQL in PHP is using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Get the data from this and make a foreach loop and echo each row of data as you want to display it. Pulling and displaying data is very basic you can find plenty of tutorials to do this in PHP.

Comment: please go to http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and study a little bit more, then you can make more detailed questions, you are asking something really basic. you can ask to my twitter account and I will help you with toturials

Comment: Thanks to you both! Will check that out.

Comment: This is very common, and there are many tutorials on producing HTML from MySQL queries.

Answer (score 6):

```
    $dbHost = 'MY_HOST_NAME';
    $dbName = 'MY_DB_NAME';
    $dbUser = 'MY_DB_USER';
    $dbPassword = 'MY_DB_PASSWORD';

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;", $dbUser, $dbPassword);
    $query = $pdo->query( 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE main_cat = "Design" ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 20');

while($res = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<div class="tablevalue">', PHP_EOL;
    echo "<h3>{$res['ROW1_Value1']}</h3>", PHP_EOL;
    echo "<span>{$res['ROW1_Value2']}</span>", PHP_EOL;
// ...
    echo "</div>", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbConn = new PDO("mysql:host=yourhostname;dbname=yourdbname","yourusername","yourpassword");

$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE main_cat = "Design" ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 20';

$stmt = $dbConn->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute();

$result_array = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Remember $result_array is an array containing all of the result set rows.

So you can print Row1_Value1 with $result_array[0][0] since array starts from 0 index position.